# How to compare values in two columns in R and print 1 or 0 if they match/don't match?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Suppose we have the following data frame:

```
id yes no
1  3   4
2  0   0
3  1   0
```

I want to compare the `yes` and `no` columns, and if `yes > no`, add 1 to a `true` column. If `yes < no`, add 1 to a `false` column, and if `yes = no`, add 1 to an `equal` column. I.e. I'd like the output to be:

```
id yes no true false equal
1  3   4  0    1     0
2  0   0  0    0     1
3  1   0  1    0     0
```

Does anyone know how this can be done in R?

Comment: i.e. `df$true <- as.numeric(df$yes>df$no)` ... The rest has the same logic.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = data.frame(id  = c(1, 2, 3),
                yes = c(3, 0, 1),
                no  = c(4, 0, 0))

library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(true  = if_else(yes > no, 1, 0),
         false = if_else(yes < no, 1, 0),
         equal = if_else(yes == no, 1, 0))
```

gives:

```
  id yes no true false equal
1  1   3  4    0     1     0
2  2   0  0    0     0     1
3  3   1  0    1     0     0
```